# VS2015 warning MSB3277 conflict between mscorlib

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2015, c++-cli, mscorlib

I am trying to upgrade a program that has three different languages from VS2008 to VS2015 and running into a warning MSB3277 which is a conflict between two different versions of mscorlib.  The languages:  native C/C++ static library, C++/CLI assembly, two C# assemblies and one final C# exe.

It looks like the native C/C++ is compiling fine, along with the C++/CLI.  The problem comes in compiling the C# exe, along with the MSB3277 it cannot see one of the namespaces defined in the C++/CLI.  My theory is that the mscorlib issue is between the C++/CLI and the C# code causing the namespace not to be found.

Here is what I get when I turn on verbose logging.  It looks to me like the 3rd party libraries which are .Net 4.0 are still using the .Net v2 of mscorlib, is that correct?  If so, how do I fix it?

```
1>  There was a conflict between "mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" and "mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e, Retargetable=Yes". (TaskId:13)
1>      "mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" was chosen because it was primary and "mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e, Retargetable=Yes" was not. (TaskId:13)
1>      References which depend on "mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" [C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.7.2\mscorlib.dll]. (TaskId:13)
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.7.2\mscorlib.dll (TaskId:13)
1>            Project file item includes which caused reference "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.7.2\mscorlib.dll". (TaskId:13)
1>              C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.7.2\mscorlib.dll (TaskId:13)
1>              System.Data.SQLite, Version=1.0.108.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139, processorArchitecture=MSIL (TaskId:13)
1>              C:\mainSolution\exeProgram\Debug\cppcliLibrary.dll (TaskId:13)
1>              Common.Logging, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=af08829b84f0328e, processorArchitecture=MSIL (TaskId:13)
1>              log4net (TaskId:13)
1>              Spring.Core, Version=2.0.1.45000, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=65e474d141e25e07, processorArchitecture=MSIL (TaskId:13)
1>          C:\licenseMgr\3rdPartyLibraries\log4net-2.0.8\bin\net\4.5\release\log4net.dll (TaskId:13)
1>            Project file item includes which caused reference "C:\licenseMgr\3rdPartyLibraries\log4net-2.0.8\bin\net\4.5\release\log4net.dll". (TaskId:13)
1>              C:\mainSolution\exeProgram\Debug\cppcliLibrary.dll (TaskId:13)
1>              log4net (TaskId:13)
1>          C:\mainSolution\exeProgram\packages\System.Data.SQLite.Core.1.0.108.0\lib\net46\System.Data.SQLite.dll (TaskId:13)
1>            Project file item includes which caused reference "C:\mainSolution\exeProgram\packages\System.Data.SQLite.Core.1.0.108.0\lib\net46\System.Data.SQLite.dll". (TaskId:13)
1>              System.Data.SQLite, Version=1.0.108.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139, processorArchitecture=MSIL (TaskId:13)
1>          C:\mainSolution\exeProgram\packages\Spring.Core.2.0.1\lib\net45\Spring.Core.dll (TaskId:13)
1>            Project file item includes which caused reference "C:\mainSolution\exeProgram\packages\Spring.Core.2.0.1\lib\net45\Spring.Core.dll". (TaskId:13)
1>              Spring.Core, Version=2.0.1.45000, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=65e474d141e25e07, processorArchitecture=MSIL (TaskId:13)
1>          C:\mainSolution\exeProgram\packages\Common.Logging.3.0.0\lib\net40\Common.Logging.dll (TaskId:13)
1>            Project file item includes which caused reference "C:\mainSolution\exeProgram\packages\Common.Logging.3.0.0\lib\net40\Common.Logging.dll". (TaskId:13)
1>              Spring.Core, Version=2.0.1.45000, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=65e474d141e25e07, processorArchitecture=MSIL (TaskId:13)
1>              Common.Logging, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=af08829b84f0328e, processorArchitecture=MSIL (TaskId:13)
1>          C:\mainSolution\exeProgram\Debug\cppcliLibrary.dll (TaskId:13)
1>            Project file item includes which caused reference "C:\mainSolution\exeProgram\Debug\cppcliLibrary.dll". (TaskId:13)
1>              C:\mainSolution\exeProgram\Debug\cppcliLibrary.dll (TaskId:13)
1>      References which depend on "mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e, Retargetable=Yes" []. (TaskId:13)
1>          C:\mainSolution\exeProgram\packages\Common.Logging.Core.3.0.0\lib\net40\Common.Logging.Core.dll (TaskId:13)
1>            Project file item includes which caused reference "C:\mainSolution\exeProgram\packages\Common.Logging.Core.3.0.0\lib\net40\Common.Logging.Core.dll". (TaskId:13)
1>              Common.Logging.Core, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=af08829b84f0328e, processorArchitecture=MSIL (TaskId:13)
1>              Common.Logging, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=af08829b84f0328e, processorArchitecture=MSIL (TaskId:13)
1>              Spring.Core, Version=2.0.1.45000, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=65e474d141e25e07, processorArchitecture=MSIL (TaskId:13)
1>          C:\mainSolution\exeProgram\packages\Spring.Core.2.0.1\lib\net45\Spring.Core.dll (TaskId:13)
1>            Project file item includes which caused reference "C:\mainSolution\exeProgram\packages\Spring.Core.2.0.1\lib\net45\Spring.Core.dll". (TaskId:13)
1>              Spring.Core, Version=2.0.1.45000, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=65e474d141e25e07, processorArchitecture=MSIL (TaskId:13)
1>          C:\mainSolution\exeProgram\packages\Common.Logging.3.0.0\lib\net40\Common.Logging.dll (TaskId:13)
1>            Project file item includes which caused reference "C:\mainSolution\exeProgram\packages\Common.Logging.3.0.0\lib\net40\Common.Logging.dll". (TaskId:13)
1>              Spring.Core, Version=2.0.1.45000, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=65e474d141e25e07, processorArchitecture=MSIL (TaskId:13)
1>              Common.Logging, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=af08829b84f0328e, processorArchitecture=MSIL (TaskId:13)
```

(also asked in Microsoft forms [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/550a5602-acd5-4a7f-b0ea-adcd5b781d3a/warning-msb3277-conflict-between-mscorlib?forum=msbuild))

Comment: That is normal, version 2.0.5.0 is a special version of mscorlib that is used by Portable Class Libraries.  Libraries that were designed to run on different kinds of platforms.  It is retargetable, the CLR resolves it to version 4.0.0.0 at runtime.  It is not the cause of your compile error.

Comment: Hans, any suggestions on what I should be looking for?  I do find the same "warning MSB3277" message in the verbosity mode, scroll through all the assemblies listed under it (long, long list) and everything is using v4 or greator.  Any suggestions?